# How can my brake discs be warped but not the pads?

Tags: brake-rotor

I bought a 2nd hand car from a dealer & had a service today. I was told that brake discs r warped but pads are fine. I only got the car sept last year & it's a year old. How can discs be warped? Very concerned as i don't think I should have to pay for this.
Would really appreciate an answer as to me it dosn't make sense
Thank you

Comment: Disc can warp for a variety of reasons, its not their fault.

Comment: If you had the car for 6 months IMO it's a little too late to complain to the dealer who sold it to you. It's probably not a warranty item either, but a "wear & tear" item that depends on the driving, not on the manufacturing.

Comment: Do you have symptoms of a warped disc - shaking/vibration when the brakes are applied ? If not, they may just be looking for business.

Answer (score 1):

Warping is not damage to the disc surface where the pads touch.  A disc could be perfectly smooth to the touch and eye and the pad perfectly flat, yet the disc could be warped.  If you rotated a warped disc, you could measure a wobble on it's friction surface using a dial gauge.  You may even be able to see the wobble.  The wobble pushes against the pads as you brake and can cause the car to shake.

Heavy braking making the brake discs get hot then quickly cooling them by driving through water can warp brand new discs.

Disc warping can happen and doesn't mean there was anything wrong with the car when you bought it.  It could even have been caused by your style of driving.

Answer (score 1):

"warped" brake rotors... most of the time, what you're feeling through the brake pedal isn't a warped rotor, it's an uneven buildup of the friction material.

This is a bit wordy... having tried the suggestions within, I can say from my own experience,that my driving habits contributed to the problem. As an experiment, I took the time to bed-in new pads (and rotors) on my last brake job and the "warped" rotor issue hasn't returned. The new parts were OEM and wheels torqued to spec.

The short take-away is, when you've braked hard (exiting the highway for ex.)and come to a stop, don't press the brake pedal any harder than necessary to keep the vehicle from moving. Replace worn parts with OEM or equivalent and make sure the wheels are torqued properly.

The long version...

Brake Rotor Run-out is measured using a dial indicator on a fixed rigid base, with the tip perpendicular to the brake disc's face. It is typically measured about 1⁄2 in (12.7 mm) from the outside diameter of the disc. The disc is spun. The difference between minimum and maximum value on the dial is called lateral run-out. Typical hub/disc assembly run-out specifications for passenger vehicles are around 0.002 in (0.0508 mm). Runout can be caused either by deformation of the disc itself or by runout in the underlying wheel hub face or by contamination between the disc surface and the underlying hub mounting surface. Determining the root cause of the indicator displacement (lateral runout) requires disassembly of the disc from the hub. Disc face runout due to hub face runout or contamination will typically have a period of 1 minimum and 1 maximum per revolution of the brake disc.

Discs can be machined to eliminate thickness variation and lateral run-out. Machining can be done in situ (on-car) or off-car (bench lathe). Both methods will eliminate thickness variation. Machining on-car with proper equipment can also eliminate lateral run-out due to hub-face non-perpendicularity.

Incorrect fitting can distort (warp) discs. The disc's retaining bolts (or the wheel/lug nuts, if the disc is sandwiched in place by the wheel) must be tightened progressively and evenly. The use of air tools to fasten lug nuts can be bad practice, unless a torque wrench is used for final tightening. The vehicle manual will indicate the proper pattern for tightening as well as a torque rating for the bolts. Lug nuts should never be tightened in a circle. Some vehicles are sensitive to the force the bolts apply and tightening should be done with a torque wrench.

Often uneven pad transfer is confused for disc warping.[40] The majority of brake discs diagnosed as "warped" are actually the result of uneven transfer of pad material. Uneven pad transfer can lead to thickness variation of the disc. When the thicker section of the disc passes between the pads, the pads will move apart and the brake pedal will raise slightly; this is pedal pulsation. The thickness variation can be felt by the driver when it is approximately 0.17 mm (0.0067 in) or greater (on automobile discs).

Thickness variation has many causes, but there are three primary mechanisms which contribute to the propagation of disc thickness variations. The first is improper selection of brake pads. Pads which are effective at low temperatures, such as when braking for the first time in cold weather, often are made of materials which decompose unevenly at higher temperatures. This uneven decomposition results in uneven deposition of material onto the brake disc. Another cause of uneven material transfer is improper break-in of a pad/disc combination. For proper break-in, the disc surface should be refreshed (either by machining the contact surface or by replacing the disc) every time the pads are changed. Once this is done, the brakes are heavily applied multiple times in succession. This creates a smooth, even interface between the pad and the disc. When this is not done properly the brake pads will see an uneven distribution of stress and heat, resulting in an uneven, seemingly random, deposition of pad material. The third primary mechanism of uneven pad material transfer is "pad imprinting." This occurs when the brake pads are heated to the point that the material begins to break-down and transfer to the disc. In a properly broken-in brake system (with properly selected pads), this transfer is natural and actually is a major contributor to the braking force generated by the brake pads. However, if the vehicle comes to a stop and the driver continues to apply the brakes, the pads will deposit a layer of material in the shape of the brake pad. This small thickness variation can begin the cycle of uneven pad transfer.

Once the disc has some level of variation in thickness, uneven pad deposition can accelerate, sometimes resulting in changes to the crystal structure of the metal that composes the disc. As the brakes are applied, the pads slide over the varying disc surface. As the pads pass by the thicker section of the disc, they are forced outwards. The foot of the driver applied to the brake pedal naturally resists this change, and thus more force is applied to the pads. The result is that the thicker sections see higher levels of stress. This causes uneven heating of the surface of the disc, which causes two major issues. As the brake disc heats unevenly it also expands unevenly. The thicker sections of the disc expand more than the thinner sections due to seeing more heat, and thus the difference in thickness is magnified. Also, the uneven distribution of heat results in further uneven transfer of pad material. The result is that the thicker-hotter sections receive even more pad material than the thinner-cooler sections, contributing to a further increase in the variation in the disc's thickness. In extreme situations, this uneven heating can cause the crystal structure of the disc material to change. When the hotter sections of the discs reach extremely high temperatures (1,200–1,300 °F or 649–704 °C ), the metal can undergo a phase transformation and the carbon which is dissolved in the steel can precipitate out to form carbon-heavy carbide regions known as cementite. This iron carbide is very different from the cast iron the rest of the disc is composed of. It is extremely hard, brittle, and does not absorb heat well. After cementite is formed, the integrity of the disc is compromised. Even if the disc surface is machined, the cementite within the disc will not wear or absorb heat at the same rate as the cast iron surrounding it, causing the uneven thickness and uneven heating characteristics of the disc to return.

Answer (score 0):

Since asbestos was banned as a brake pad material, the pads are harder than the discs so the discs usually wear faster.

The amount of distortion on warped brake pads is too small to see by eye. Common symptoms are vibration through the brake pedal or steering wheel when you apply the brakes, and/or noises when you apply the brakes..

One cause of warped disks is that the brake calipers are partially seized and the pads are continuously rubbing on a disk and overheating it.

I expect you will have a hard time proving this type of fault existed when you bought the car if there were no symptoms at that time.

Comment: The first sentence of your answer is inaccurate. Pads wear MUCH faster than rotors. Think about the thickness of both and figure out which one wears out first? It would have to be the pads, because you can still cut the rotors again and have a servicable one.